# How to set @key inside a partial template? (Or why is it impossible?)

Tags: handlebars.js

I've a partial template, representing one row in a table, that is also used directly from Javascript (see background below). Here is how I use it as a partial:

```
{{#each this}}
{{> my_onerow}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is a simplified `my_onerow`:

```
<div>{{@key}}: {{x}}, {{y}}</div>
```

I have those templates available as `JST.my` and `JST.my_onerow`, so my JavaScript looks like:

```
var obj={
  one:{x:"this",y:"that"},
  two:{x:55,y:77},
  three:{x:"hello",y:"world"}
  };
$('body').append(JST.my(obj));
```

`@key` is available in the partial, so I get this:

```
<div>one: this, that</div>
<div>two: 55, 77</div>
<div>three: hello, world</div>
```

Then, when I want to add another row, directly from JavaScript, I do:

```
var newObj = {x:"new",y:"entry"};
$('body').append(JST.my_onerow(newObj));
```

This also works fine, but `@key` is `""`, and I don't know a way to define it. This does not work:

```
var newObj = {"@key":"four",x:"new",y:"entry"};
```

My question is: how can I define `@key` when using the `JST.my_onerow` template directly? Or, if it is impossible, can anyone give some insight into the internals of Handlebars to explain why it is not something that can easily be added?

(I'm using handlebars 1.3.0.)

---

Background: I do this by creating it as a normal template, compiled into `JST`, then I make all templates available as partials with this line:

```
Handlebars.partials = JST;
```

This bit works fine. I just mention it as an aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Self-answer with the hack-ish workaround I currently use, just in case what I really want to do is impossible.)

What I currently do is preprocess the data, to add the object keys inside the value part, as a `key` member. This is done just before using `JST.my`:

```
for(key in obj)obj.key = key;
$('body').append(JST.my(obj));
```

Then I changed `my_onerow` to look like this:

```
<div>{{key}}: {{x}}, {{y}}</div>
```

Now of course I can specify `key` easily enough when adding the row directly from JavaScript.